# Why the order is reverse in equals()

Tags: java, syntax

In part of the code for check empty string the programmer use `equals()` like this:

```
if ("".equals(name)) {
    // some logic
}
```

Why is it executed from a string value directly? What is the difference from this;

```
if (name.equals("")) {
    // some logic
}
```

Both of them have the same result, but what is the idea behind doing the first one?

Comment: It is called a "yoda condition".  Empty string the name is, hmmm?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea behind using;

```
"".equals(name)
```

is that `""` can never be `null`, whereas `name` can be. `equals()` accepts `null` as a parameter, but trying to execute a method from a `null` variable will result in a `NullPointerException`.

So this is a shorthand way to evade such possible exceptions. Same goes for any such constant object.

e.g.

```
final Integer CONSTANT_RATE = 123456;
....

if (CONSTANT_RATE.equals(someVariable)) { .. }
```

rather than doing;

```
if (someVariable != null && someVariable.equals(CONSTANT_RATE)) { .. }
```